# What does "a relaxed market" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Can anybody explain the phrases in bold for me, please?

“Our bottom line is markets are a bit too **[relaxed](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/relaxed)**,” Clarida said. “They are priced, **if not for perfection, certainly for a continued run of good luck.**”

Source: [Chance of a recession by 2022 is 70 percent, according to this major investment firm](https://www.washingtonpost.com/business/economy/chance-of-a-recession-by-2022-is-70-percent-according-to-this-major-investment-firm/2017/05/31/95b4873a-461a-11e7-98cd-af64b4fe2dfc_story.html?utm_term=.6ff18e15d0f2) (The Washington Post)

Comment: It is the opposite of a *tense* market.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I have not heard the usage before, I think the meaning is fairly literal. The stock market is often said to be "[jittery](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marketjitters.asp)", meaning that any little problem will cause investors (or more likely the computers that drive automated trading) to sell, causing stock prices to drop or be very volatile.

Here it is the opposite of the market being jittery, in the speaker's view, it's relaxed. Thus he thinks the market is in for a good run of increasing stock values.